# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' Vs code

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pip, python-3.7

I am running on windows 10. I am having problems with importing TensorFlow. I am in Vs code. I installed tensorflow using pip3. And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/tt/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I created my project in pycharm.
I am using python 3.7.5 and TensorFlow 2.0.0. This is how I installed TF:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

please help I was having this problem for a week.

Thanks , In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your work/project, please try to create a new virtual environment and then install all your required packages.

Like this:

```
$ python3 -m venv env
```

Activate it:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

and then install the tensorflow package inside your virtual environment:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Comment: didn't work for me, it looks like it installed, but vscode still says it is missing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create environment separate

and then install tensorflow..

for more information regarding envirnoment [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: thank you for your support but I just found a simpler way

Comment: @KIDUSSisay would you mind sharing? I installed using venv also but no help in vs cdoe. It still throws the same error

Comment: @Veronica do pip3 install TensorFlow inside your venv, sorry for not replying, didn't check this for a while

Comment: @KIDUSSisay hey, no worries. I don't remember how but I somehow solved my issue using online resources and help :) Take care

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several different python environments on your pc? Which python interpreter are you using when you install tensorflow?
The Status Bar will show you the current interpreter in the lower left corner. Check whether it is the same with the one you use when you install tensorflow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBjm3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting your exact error, but this worked for me:

1. File->settings
2. Workspace tab
3. Search for "interpreter"
4. Put the complete path to the python.exe you want to execute under "default interpreter path"

It seems VSCode either found (or included) an older version of python that couldn't find the things I installed with pip.

I am a bit of a python newb and I'm guessing the venv approach is superior, but I couldn't get that cooperating with VSCode on windows.

Answer (score 0):

If:

- you have a conda environment on a remote machine with tensorflow installed
- you have that environment active in vs code
- that environment is showing all other updates (pip version, other installed packages) in your remote environment and in your vs code terminal

You may need to install tensorflow via pip from inside your vs code terminal. I know this sounds silly - you already did this in your remote environment. I can't explain it either.